# How to set TLS version in httplib2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, tls1.2

I am using python 3.4, and I need to set TLS version to 1.2 for httplib2.Http instance. But there is no obvious way to do that. Is there any way to set custom SSLContext for that instance?